# Книга по Unity

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!

Вопроса такого не нашел (**искал, честно**), так что задам.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу по unity3D.
Если уже есть русскоязычная, то лучше её. Но можно и англоязычную. Главное, чтобы учебник подошел новичку.

---

*Да, я понимаю, что подобные вопросы уже глаза мозолят.*

Comment: [link](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Unity-Book-Roundup.aspx) на самом деле искать такие книги на русском это практически бесполезное дело. да и что нового будет в книгах ? все есть в офф.документации, на stackoverflow, на youtube и на различных других сайтах. Просто нужно поискать.

Comment: Советую вот эти посмотреть - http://rutracker.org/forum/tracker.php?f=1563&nm=Walker%20Boys%20Studio

Comment: люблю читать учебники. Ну во всяком случае больше, чем смотреть обучающие видео. Ну знаете, как это бывает - укутываешься в теплый плед, рядом стоит кружечка горячего шоколада, а в руках хорошая книга.

подправил теги

Comment: >все есть в офф.документации, на stackoverflow, на youtube и на различных других сайтах

учиться по ютубу? Вы б ещё курсы Попова посоветовали

Comment: @DreamChild, хорошо, что  я не знаю, кто такой г-н Попов?

Comment: @DreamChild, а что плохого в видео-курсах ?

Comment: @teanЫЧ извините конечно, но вы с такой регулярностью ежедневно обновляете этот вопрос, не внося в него совершенно никаких изменений чтобы он подольше повисел в топе? Я боюсь, вам вряд ли дадут удовлетворяющий вас ответ, поскольку таких книг (во всяком случае на русском) судя по всему просто нет.

Comment: @DreamChild, я Вас, конечно, извиняю) Но если мне память не изменяет, я поднимал вопрос всего 2 раза в день (1 тык рано утром и 1 тык поздно вечером). Если этим я захламляю вам ленту, то обещаю, что буду делать это реже - один раз в пару дней.  
А в вопросе я написал, что иностранной литературой я не брезгую. И вообще, я считаю, что ответ положительный будет, рано или поздно. Ибо сообщество unity developer'ов растет, и не только за бугром, и знания они черпают не из космоса.  
И просто так абы какую книжку читать не хочется. Надо сразу нормально все делать.  
Так что и вы меня извините.

Comment: @teanЫЧ кстати, может [вот эта книжица][1] будет вам полезна? 

[1]:http://vk.com/doc187705827_284866186?hash=a7d605271ae7470b89&dl=0716f114ff7cd8b155

Comment: AI? Очень даже интересно. Страница, безусловно, будет полезна, но чуть позже. Спасибо.

Comment: Неужели человек с 3000 репутации не знает, что тут запрещены вопросы о поиске литературы?

Answer (score 1):

Видео

- Design3 - Complete set of Unity3D tutorials

Книжки

- *Grome Terrain Modeling with Ogre3D UDK and Unity3D*. Richard A. Hawley
- *Game Development for iOS with Unity3D*. Jeff W. Murray

Answer (score 0):

1. Учебник [Unity 3.x Game Development Essentials](http://unitybook.net/downloads/). Не смотря на то, что учебник на английском языке, проблем при чтении практически не возникает, даже при условии поверхностных знаний языка. Все написано доступно и подробно.
2. [Документация](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/)

Answer (score 0):

Unity Game Development Essentials RUS - https://yadi.sk/i/obPyfIp6ZfzBq
Правда перевод на любителя.

Здесь есть некоторые статьи для новичка - http://gamesmaker.ru/3d-game-engines/unity3d/

Группа в вк там же есть и книги - https://vk.com/unity_engine

Форум русскоязычных геймдевов - http://unity3d.ru/distribution/index.php