# Движок для игры

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Всем привет!

Совсем недавно решил заняться программированием игр на C#. Пока я не собираюсь делать супер серьезные игры, в которых нет недочетов или что-то вроде этого. На данный момент я хочу начать с чего-нибудь очень простенького. Например, игра-головоломка с шариком, который должен двигать ящики, нажимать на кнопки, чтобы открывать какие-либо двери и так далее, и тому подобное.

Прошу вас дать мне совет по поводу того, какой двигатель использовать для создания игры, подсказать, какие двигатели работают с C# и так далее.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самый известный "движок", который известен большим количеством выпущенных на нем игр, начиная от самых простых до супер сложных, - это *unity3d*.

Официальный сайт, где есть документация и можно скачать его: [ссылка](http://unity3d.com/).

Я, конечно, не знаю Ваш скилл, но компьютерная игра - это весьма сложная структура, даже если это какой-нибудь тетрис или катающийся шарик. Но, конечно, даже если уровень не высок, то за время попыток что-либо написать у Вас появится много новых практических знаний.

На **unity3d** можно программировать как 2D, так и 3D игры. Почитайте статью с [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA)), там есть много подробностей относительно "движка".

Поддерживаемые языки: **C#**, **JavaScript**, **Boo (Python)**.

По поводу бесплатности: на unity3d можно делать, как бесплатные, так и платные игры без какой-либо оплаты создателям "движка", но если захотите кроссплатформености (чтобы игра запускалась и на Linux и Mac OS), то здесь придется заплатить. Такие же правила действуют и для некоторых других функций, которых нет в "бесплатной" версии движка, но эти функции не критичны для создания игры.

Относительно **книги по unity3d**, их мало:

1. [Книга Терри Нортона о создании игр на Unity3d](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27421581/?partner=ilja_blog)
2. [Книга для начинающих с примерами о разработке игр на Unity3d](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27407322/?partner=ilja_blog)

**Уроки, туториалы на русском и английском**:

4. [google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+unity3d),
5. [yandex](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?lr=2&text=%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+unity3d&csg=1571%2C4362%2C13%2C16%2C1%2C0%2C0&suggest_reqid=93802691142376635016844861368837)
6. [Видео уроки](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unity+3d&oq=unity&aq=2&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=youtube-psuggest.3.2.0l10.4211.5332.0.8044.5.5.0.0.0.0.341.854.2j1j1j1.5.0...0.0.8LVua0CVWFw)
7. [Переводы уроков по unity3d](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141362/)
8. [Поиск уроков на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=Unity+3D+)
9. [Туториалы на английском от walkerboystudio](http://walkerboystudio.com/)
10. [Tуториалы на английском от unity3dstudent](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/)
11. [Туториалы на английском от design3](http://www.design3.com/)
12. [Туториалы на английском от digitaltutors](http://www.digitaltutors.com/training/unity-tutorials)
13. [Уроки на русском от unity3d.ru](http://unity3d.ru/)
14. [Уроки и туториалы от cgcookie.com](http://cgcookie.com/unity/)

И отдельно по информации: на Хэшкоде уже были вопросы по литературе, посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/310952/c-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-unity) еще ссылки.

К счастью, по этому движку масса документации, уроков и статей, в общем, разбирайтесь! Удачи! :)