# Литература\справочник по c#+unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Посоветуйте толковую литературку по `с#` для `unity`. После `с++` меня пугает обилие "сахара" в шарпе, а особенно в связке c#+unity, ибо там что-то совсем специфичное. Пробовал видеоуроки, но это, скорее, инструкция в стиле "делай раз, делай два". Это мне не совсем подходит, т.к. хочется чуть более глубокого подхода к изучению. Видел здесь хороший ответ про книги про `с#` вообще, но про `с#+unity` - нет. Поэтому возникла потребность в некоем "справочнике". Поделитесь советом где такое можно найти, желательно онлайн и на русском(ибо на английском есть неплохая wiki на сайте unity, но на родном читать все-таки приятнее). Спасибо.

Comment: У нас такие вопросы [традиционно считаются неформатом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/162#162). Так что в любой момент могут прилететь закрывашки.

Comment: @D-side Это да, но всё равно вопрос очень толковый и уверен, будет полезен, если ему дадут хотя бы немного времени пожить.

Comment: @D-side тут кстати нужно бы завести раздел с книгами по Unity. А то по языкам есть, а по движку — нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский надо. Есть кому?

Comment: @D-side с миру по нитке наберется, думаю.... начать нужно, так или иначе...попробую на днях хотя бы парочку кинуть :)

Comment: Посмотрите пока список https://gcup.ru/forum/8-46855-1 попробуйте оттуда что-то..... совсем совсем для бегиннеров (самый плинтус):  `Terry Norton - Learning C sharp by Developing Games with Unity 3D`  просто для бегиннеров: `Хокинг Джозеф — Unity в действии`. Что-то более продвинутое адекватное, пока не знаю.....возмоооожно `Алан Торн - Искусство создания сценариев в Unity (Alan Thorn - Mastering Unity Scripting)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По Unity нет ничего лучше чем официальные  документация. И официальные видео уроки (частично переведена)
https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials

У них же есть уроки и по C#

https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting

И как рекомендация, лично от меня - в изучении юнити стоит пользоваться только этими материалами. Все остальное что найдешь на ютубе и тд - делают весьма сомнительные личности и часто используют не верный подход(в общем плохому научат).

Похожий вопрос: 
[Книга по Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/310952/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-unity)

Comment: у нас есть метка [tag:книги] где есть разделы  с литературой по языкам. Потихоньку собирают люди, а вопросы с книжками закрывают как дубли тех вопросо-ответов..... Предлагаю потихоньку начать создавать такой общий вопрос-ответ по Юнити ;-)